# how to enable other reporter than dot-matrix in mocha on windows?

Tags: mocha.js

I am new to mocha and just wrote few simple test and it works but the output after command `mocha` is in `dot-matrix` format (http://visionmedia.github.io/mocha/#reporters). It is possible to use other formats (like `Spec` format also under link above) on windows console?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use one of the other reporters use `-R <reporterName>` or `--reporter <reporterName>`like described in [here](http://mochajs.org/#reporters).

```
mocha -R spec
```